# Start a windows service only after method is finished

Tags: c#, methods, service

I am a beginner in c# and need a help in sorting out the following problem.
In my program, I want to start a service but only after the a method is completed. For example,

```
    {
       // A method which copies file
       A(); 
       // A service that uses the copied files in function A()
       ServiceController service = new ServiceController("ServiceName"); 
       service.Start();
    }
```

Problem is that the service has already started, but the the method A() has not finished copying yet. 
Any idea or help is most welcomed!

Comment: Did you try to Google how to start a service in c#?

Comment: As he stated he is a beginner with C#. In the beginning the results from google can be quite confusing there if you have no prior experience with C#. Although I have to admit a beginner starting with a service is something I haven't seen (I find services thanks to the difficulty in debugging them compared to normal c# programs more difficult than normal programs)

Comment: At the originalposter: Can you explain why the service itself does not check for the files existence and copies it if necessary? (as with what you wrote how the program shall function it would be so that EVERY time the service is started the file is copied and then the service is started instead of it only being copied if necessary [which could be any time the service is running as a service is normally running not only once)

Comment: @Thomas Being a beginner doesn't mean you are unable to use Google

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Starting a service a service is not a probem. But how to make it wait till the method has finished its work.

Comment: The code you posted already waits until `A` is complete. Execution cannot continue until it has exited.

Comment: DavidG, this is exactly what should happen. But I am getting the results otherwise.

Comment: then it is best if you add some code of what A() does (if it does for example start a thread that does the copying then it is clear why it does not wait,...)  also that method is only called once while the service is run time and again (if it has a loop)

Comment: Thomas, thanks I have already added it as error handling.

Comment: The method A() is simply directory copy code. It copies files from a network drive to local drive. Nothing fancy.

Comment: And there is no loop in service. It stops itself when it is done processing the copied file.

Comment: T have an idea. I will probably start the service in method A() itself.

Comment: and why not go the other way round and make A() part of the service? (would be a cleaner way imho).  Also a question there even if it has nothing to do with the original question: Why a service there and not just a normal program that is run via the autostart of windows?

Comment: Thanks Thomas for ideas. Starting service in A() is better for me to go. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

> You can use the ServiceController class to connect to and control the
>   behavior of existing services. When you create an instance of the
>   ServiceController class, you set its properties so it interacts with a
>   specific Windows service. You can then use the class to start, stop,
>   and otherwise manipulate the service.

**Couple of suggestions**

1. You can invoke method A() synchronously from main method so that succeeding service start() code will only be executed after A() completes.
2. If there is no restrictions and if you have access to code where A() resides, Why don't you move the windows service start() logic to your method A(), probably you can place the logic at the end of the method A()

---

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
  A();

  ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("WindowsServiceName");
  controller.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the service has already started but the function A() is not finished copying yet.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably call it in the methods A().